Getting HTTP to work on GSM SIM7080
I am trying to get GSM sim7080 to connect to http server.
They have application note for http server and obviously that example works.
Now what I am trying to do is simply read the .txt file while connecting to this website
https://txt2html.sourceforge.net/sample.txt
Which is being failed and I am also little bit confused.
Here enter code here is the application example code for http
               //Example of HTTP GET. 

AT+SHCONF="URL","http://httpbin.org" OK
            //Set up server URL
            AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024
            OK
            //Set HTTP body length, for range of maxbodylength
            AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350
            OK
            //Set HTTP head length, for range of maxheadlength
            AT+SHCONN
            OK
            //HTTP build
            AT+SHSTATE?
            +SHSTATE: 1
            OK
            //Get HTTP status
            //“+SHSTATE: 1”: connected
            //“+SHSTATE: 0”: disconnected
            AT+SHCHEAD
            OK
            //Clear HTTP header, because of http header isappended
         
           AT+SHAHEAD="User-Agent","curl/7.47.0" 
           OK
            //Add header content
            //For detail, please refer to document "rfc2616" 
        
        AT+SHAHEAD="Cache-control","no-cache" 
    OK
            //Add header content
            //For detail, please refer to document "rfc2616" 
        
        AT+SHAHEAD="Connection","keep-alive" 
    OK
            //Add header content
            //For detail, please refer to document "rfc2616" 
        AT+SHAHEAD="Accept","*/*" 
    OK
            //Add header content
            //For detail, please refer to document "rfc2616" 
        
        AT+SHREQ="/get?user=jack&password=123", 1
          
          OK
            +SHREQ: "GET",200,387
            //Set request type is GET.
            //Get data size is 387. 
        
        AT+SHREAD=0,387 //Read data length is 387
            OK
            +SHREAD: 387
            { "args": { "password": "123", "user": "jack"
            },"headers": { "Accept": "*/*", "Cache-Control": "no-cache", "Content-Length": "0", "Host": "httpbin.org", "User-Agent": "curl/7.47.0", "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5ed706c8-99b97372ae6f043f805cf243
            "
            },"origin": "117.132.195.245", "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?user=jack&password=1
            23"
            }
            //The data content is follow “+SHREAD: 387”
            AT+SHDISC
            OK

Now here is my test code which I am tryiung to read the text file from https://txt2html.sourceforge.net/sample.txt
AT+SHCONF="URL","http://txt2html.sourceforge.net"
OK
AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024
OK
AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350
OK
AT+SHCONN
OK
AT+SHCHEAD
OK
AT+SHAHEAD="User-Agent","curl/7.47.0"
OK
AT+SHAHEAD="Cache-control","no-cache"
OK
AT+SHAHEAD="Connection","keep-alive"
OK
AT+SHAHEAD="Accept","*/*"
OK
AT+SHREQ="/sample.txt",1
OK

+SHSTATE: 0

Now as you see I tried to read the txt file and it failed.
Can someone help me what I am doing wrong or what resources should I look deeper to get it working. As my end code is just to read the binary file from the server.

http://httpbin.org accept non-secure http access. But http://txt2html.sourceforge.net doesn't, it re-direct to https and require you to connect with https. Download SIM7070_SIM7080_SIM7090 Series_HTTP(S)_Application Note to see how use HTTPS. The application note is free but require registration before you could download it.

Ya, I tried with https as well but no luck.

Well, It does not depend on luck but curiosity and try-and-error. First, you need to load the cert into the module, the module doesn't hold any cert like your browser and PC did. Secondly, you need to use the root CA cert instead of the server cert...

I actually tried with sites that support http and that did not also work. I was testing along side using postman by accessing http and on postman it was working fine. I think the issue here is for some reason this module does not accept commands like this and pattern is different. I have done fair amount of testing related to tcp and http so I have some idea, but I am lost here.
